# add two decimal? LINQ results in c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
var total= jobs.Where(x => x.num == pNum).Sum(x => x.amount);

var totalTwo= person.Where(x => x.num == pNum).Sum(x => x.amount);
```

I would like to add the result of both LINQ queries. If one is null, the result needs to add the null/empty string value of firs total to the second total

```
if (total== null)
    total = "0";
ViewBag.OverallTotal = total += totalTwo;
```

ViewBag throws an invalid argument error

Comment: if jobs[n].amount is decimal, why do you think total can be null, why do you assign a string to total, why do you add the totaltwo to total in that way, what are you doing?

Comment: As has been said it would be really helpful to clarify the types of your variables. Also are the `total` in your first block in the same scope as your `total` from the second block? I assume since one is being assigned a sum and the other a string that we are looking at two different methods here. Lastly what does "add the null/empty string value of firs total to the second total". My thought would be that if a sum is null that you'd just treat it as zero. Is this what you want or is there some more complicated logic here?

Comment: @torsan thanks. It worked!

Comment: Not sure what happened to my comment, but I seems to be deleted? Anyhow here the code: `var total = jobs.Where(x => x.num == pNum).Sum(x => x.amount) ?? 0;` to assign total to 0 if the LINQ expression returns `null`.